# How to configure SaltStack to work on other machines

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, saltstack

I have installed SaltStack in my system (Ubuntu 12.04). for example If i want to run `sudo apt-get update` or `wget` to  other machines like 4 to 5 machines using Salt. How should i want to configure my SaltStack to work on this machines.

Comment: i have added the ip of two machines to /etc/salt/minion of my machine

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me how you are setting up infrastructure so I will assume that you are setting up the simple use case where your current Ubuntu 12.04 machine is the salt master and all the other machines are minions. In that case, have you tried reading the official documentation [here](http://docs.saltstack.com/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html)?

Basically, on each system that you want to be controlled by the salt-master you would install salt-minion. Then you would edit the /etc/salt/minion file on each of the systems to point to the salt master. On a default minion configuration file you could run the following command.

```
sed -i 's/^#master: salt/master: IP_OF_YOUR_MASTER/'
```

What this command basically does is it looks for the commented out option "#master: salt" and replaces it with an uncommented option that points to where you master is.

Restart your salt-minion and then on the salt-master run

```
salt-key -A
```

To accept each of your minion's keys. You can then run a ping from the salt-master to test connectivity from your master to your minions.

```
salt "*" test.ping --show-timeout
```

Comment: sed -i 's/^#master: salt/master: IP_OF_YOUR_MASTER/
please let me know IP_OF_YOUR_MASTER/ is IP_OF_MY_MACHINE right? and let me know what is s/^#master and whether it is a command or needs to  be edited. Thanks in advance

Comment: How do i want to configure the /etc/salt/minion to point out the salt master

Comment: You would want to configure the /etc/salt/minion to point to machine that you have salt-master installed. So let's say on 10.1.10.2 you ran the command "yum install salt-master" and on 10.1.10.3 you ran the command "yum install salt-minion". Then on the /etc/salt/minion of 10.1.10.3 you would run the command "sed -i 's/^#master: salt/master: 10.1.10.2" so that the minions points to the master. You would then restart the services and run salt-key -L on the master.

Comment: "sed -i 's/^#master: salt/master:192.168.2.30"
-bash: sed -i 's/^#master: salt/master:10.1.10.2: No such file or directory

Comment: You have to put the location of the minion file in order to run the command. In your case it would be sed -i 's/^#master: salt/master:192.168.2.30/" /etc/salt/minion

Comment: this is the /etc/salt/minion 0f 192.168.2.27
#### Primary configuration settings #####


# Per default the minion will automatically include all config files
# from minion.d/*.conf (minion.d is a directory in the same directory
# as the main minion config file).
#default_include: minion.d/*.conf

# Set the location of the salt master server, if the master server cannot be
# resolved, then the minion will fail to start.
master: 192.168.2.30
"sed -i 's/^#master: salt/master:192.168.2.30"
# Set whether the minion should connect to the master via IPv6
#ipv6: False

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to install a package contains like vim,mongodb,svn,python etc. how do i create package contain these things? let me know

Comment: Please open a new question as the question in your above comment does not have anything to do with configuring salt.